# Problems with DataContext

Tags: wpf

```
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:LoginViewModule.ViewModel"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
d:DataContext="{Binding Source={viewModel:LoginContentViewModel}}">
```

It is saying that:

> LoginContentViewModel doesnt exists and invalid markup extension.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your LoginViewModel situated not in folder "ViewModel". Check manualy where is it and set reference on right folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuilding first, it may just be that it can't see the ViewModel yet.

If that doesn't work you can do it like this, though this is not ignored by the xaml processor:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:LoginContentViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Or if you are wishing for it to be ignored by the xaml processor this should work:

```
d:DataContext="{Binding viewModel:LoginContentViewModel}"
```

EDIT: Make sure your namespaces are correct, otherwise none of the above will have any effect.

Your folder structure does not necessarily mean that your namespaces are in that layout. You need to check the LoginContentViewModel.cs to make sure that the namespace there is `LoginViewModule.ViewModel` and not just `LoginViewModule` which would have occurred if you added your files to your root directory and then moved them into the folder

Comment: Are you certain that `LoginContentViewModel` is in the `LoginViewModule.ViewModel` namespace, and not, say in the `LoginViewModule` namespace?

Comment: where is located the "LoginContentViewModel"?

Comment: Now it says "No constructor with 2 parameters found"

Comment: That is likely unrelated. Find the constructor, and check it's definition. It's worth noting that in order to define a Datacontext in xaml, you need a Constructor with no parameters

Comment: its located in LoginViewModule >> ViewModel

Comment: What is the namespace in LoginContentViewModel.cs? It should be `LoginContentViewModel.ViewModel` for your methods to work.

Comment: I already have constructor with no params also have [ImportingConstructor], what the hell does he want from me...

Comment: Are you still having an issue with the Datacontext, or is this now a new issue?

Comment: project name is LoginViewModule and that class LoginContentViewModel is in ViewModel solution folder... It is in the right place...

Comment: It may be in the right folders, but folders do not necessarily dictate the namespace. Check your defined namespace in the LoginContentViewModel.cs file.

Comment: did your project is small? Any changes to upload it?